# Output text using read system call C++

Tags: c++, filesystems, user-permissions

Attempts to read the first 10 characters (using the read system call, which  automatically stops if the end of file is reached before the specified number of characters) into an array,
Displays the characters read on the console,
Closes the file (using the close system call).

////This is the code I have/////Didn't include headers////

```
using namespace std;

int main(){

std::string writeToFile;

int file;

char buf[128];

int nread;

char pathNameTest[100];

pathNametest[0] = 'f';

pathNametest[0] = '\0';

cout << "Enter a file name without spaces: " endl;

cin >> pathNameTest;

file = open(pathNametest, O_RDONLY);

if(file == -1)

{

cout << "Error"

exit(0);

}

else
{

while(nread= read(file, buf, 10) > 0){

printf("%s",buf);

}

return 0;

}
```

It prints up to 10 characters like I want it to but for some reason it prints extra unknown characters. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `read()` doesn't null-terminate the buffer (it can be used for binary data).

Comment: The expression `read = read(...) > 0` does not work as you expect. Read about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Also, why use `printf` to print the "string" you read? `std::cout` can output both C-style strings as well as `std::string` objects.

Comment: Thanks but I am still unsure how to go about fixing this or how to null terminate the buffer

Comment: Null terminating could be as simple as `buf[nread] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Abhay Nayak is close, but since you are reading 10 characters into your buffer, you'll need memset 11 bytes, not 10, in order to ensure that the null character follows your last character.

```
memset( buf, 0, 11 );
```

It might be overkill, but in the general case, you should clear the entire  buffer to be safe. 
Note: I would have just commented on Abhay's post, but I don't have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

clear the buffer using memset before reading it using

```
memset(buf,0,10);
```